# query to get average and distinct in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a data in table like this:

```
================================
class | name   | study | average
================================
1       alfa     c#       70 
1       beta     c#       70
2       carlie   c#       80
2       delta    c#       80
1       alfa     php      80
1       beta     php      90
2       carlie   php      70
2       delta    php      80
```

and i want the result like this :

```
===============================
study |   class    | avg class
      | 1   |   2  |
===============================
c#      70    80       75
php     85    75       80
```

so how to make a query in mysql to get those results?

please help me, I've tried many times but have not been successful

Thanks

Comment: A query which returns a dynamic number of columns is not possible in MySQL(afaik). You should do some post processing in the application to achieve that. Also you should be aware that an an average of averages would give the wrong result most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    study,
    AVG
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN class = 1 THEN average
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) class_1_average,
    AVG
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN class = 2 THEN average
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) class_2_average,
    AVG(average) avg_class
FROM mytable
GROUP BY study;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, but you'll have to add in a new "class" line for each of your numerical class numbers.

```
SELECT study,
    (SELECT AVG(average) FROM test t WHERE class='1' AND t.study = test.study) as 'class 1',
    (SELECT AVG(average) FROM test t WHERE class='2' AND t.study = test.study) as 'class 2',
    AVG(average)
FROM test
GROUP BY study
```

[Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dee12/4)

Comment: I think average in the last column should be like this `(SELECT AVG(average) FROM test t WHERE t.study = test.study)` as you still want to filter by study.

Comment: The GROUP BY takes care of that.